# How can I represent images as a 2-D points

Tags: image, matlab

I have images (shreds) and a dissimilarity matrix of these images .
How can I find a virtual coordinates that represent these images in 2-D (convert each image to one point with x & y coordinates) .
These coordinates should be order-respecting according to the dissimilarity matrix which mean if the true order of the images is : 5 - 2 - 1 - 7 - 3 - 4 - 6 .
Then when I find these coordinates and calculate new distance matrix between them it should give the same order .
I'm writing my code in Matlab and I used mdscale (a built-in function) and it's not work good

```
 [coordinates,stress] = mdscale(D,2) ;
```

It find the coordinates, but it's not order-respecting and I tried another code in R but i didn't get a right solution .

This problem called "Non-classical Multidimensional Scaling" .
Any one can help me to find the true solution and I will be thankful for him/her.

Comment: i'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but the `mdscale` docs indicate that the second argument is the output dimensionality. you've used `mdscale(D,2)` - how could your output points respect the order if they live in a 2D space? do you get a sensible result with `mdscale(D,1)`?

Comment: I want to find points that represent images
As you mentioned above in mdscale(D,2) the second argument is the output dimensionality which mean in this case this function should return array of points with x & y coordinates which I want, but my problem is this function is not order-respecting ( for example when you find these points and calculate the distance matrix between them if the dissimilarity matrix show that the true order of the images is : 5 - 2 - 1 - 7 - 3 - 4 - 6 the distance matrix should give the same order which isn't happen here "this is the problem")
@DaveKielpinski

Comment: points on a 2D plane have no natural order, so there is no way for this map to be order-preserving

Comment: The solution is to use t-SNE